# Failing to create MQSQL database in python (cursor = db.cursor() not working) - Newbie Question

Tags: python, mysql, database

Following a tutorial video to learn how to make my first database as follows:

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect()
host="localhost"
user="root"
passwd="xxxxxxxx"
```

However when i use the following (>>> cursor = db.cursor(), this error msg shows up... not sure what has happened as i don't understand anything yet.)

```
cursor = db.cursor()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\asans\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 809, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

I'm following the 1st video in a series of tutprials by 'Tech with Tim' on youtube. Also checked https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/mysql-python#CD and that website seems to use the same command with no issues :(

Any ideas?

I'm using python 3.8.4 btw

Comment: Surprising that the `connect` line does not err out having no parameters!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the data in the parenthesis and seperate them with commas like below

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host= 'localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='xxxxxxxx')
mycursor = db.cursor()
```

Comment: Ok, this way shows there is a refusal of access by my machine and states the port number. Is there something else i need to start up before doing this?

   File "C:\Users\asans\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 511, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Comment: No that is copied directly from my VS code, but of course you need a mysql server running at  the local computer. there should be a service named mysql be running at your machine. that said did you install mysql server at your computer?

Comment: Yes I did download it all. I checked on my control panel>uninstall programmes that mysql server was installed - perhaps there was an issue. I didn't check to see if there was a mysql service running on task manager though before deleting it all. I'll download again, give it a go and be sure to check the service is running this time. Thanks for the help!